# $2^a +1$ is not divisible by $2^b-1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $a,b>2$ be positive integers. We need to show that $2^a +1$ is not divisible by $2^b-1$.

Could any one give me hint?

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but have you tried looking at mods (e.g. mod 3, 5, 7)?

Comment: Wlog $a>b>1$. $2^b\equiv1\Rightarrow 2^a\equiv1^{a-b}$ mod $(2^b-1)$.

Comment: except that isn't WLOG since divisibility is not symmetric.

Comment: Indeed, it isn't wlog by symmetry, it's wlog for other reasons.

Comment: See also: [For $a,b>2$, $a,b\in \Bbb{N}$ , prove that $2^a+1$ is never divisible by $2^b-1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1759582/for-a-b2-a-b-in-bbbn-prove-that-2a1-is-never-divisible-by-2b-1)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let $b$ be a  fixed positive integer. If there is a $k$ such that $2^b-1$ divides $2^k+1$, then there is a smallest such $k$. Call this smallest $k$ by the name $a$.

We first show that $a\lt b$. Suppose to the contrary that $a\ge b$. Note that
$$2^a+1=2^{a-b}(2^b-1) +2^{a-b}+1.$$
Thus if $2^b-1$ divides $2^a+1$, then $2^{b}-1$ divides $2^{a-b}+1$, contradicting the minimality of $a$.

It follows that $2^b-1$ divides $2^a+1$ for some $a\lt b$. In particular, $2^b-1\le 2^a+1\le 2^{b-1}+1$.

From $2^b-1\le 2^{b-1}+1$, we conclude that $2^{b}-2^{b-1}=2^{b-1}\le 2$. Thus $b-1\le 1$ and therefore $b\le 2$.

**Remark:** If $b=1$, then $2^b-1$ divides $2^a+1$ for all $a$. If $b=2$, then $2^b-1$ (that is, $3$) divides $2^a+1$ for all odd values of $a$.

Comment: I love infinite descent arguments. This is a pretty clever one.

Comment: Very nice argument. It shows that in general $y^a+1$ is not divisible by $y^b-1$ for any $y>1$, right?

Comment: With a small number of exceptions!

Comment: Can you explain the last line a little more please?

Comment: Will try, tomorrow  (it is past midnight).

Comment: @James: Done! I have written out everything, particularly the end, in great detail.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome. Note that the structure of the proof "explains" why $b=2$ is an exception. $2^b-1$ is almost always bigger than $2^{b-1}+1$, but not quite always!