# $2^{b}-1$ does not divide $2^{a}+1$

Tags: divisibility

If $a$ and $b>2$ are any positive integers, then prove that $2^{a}+1$ is not divisible by  $2^{b}-1$

Here's my attempt: 
If $2^{b}-1\mid 2^{a}+1$
then it is obvious that $a>b$.
Now ,By division algorithm
$$a=qb+r$$

We know that $$2^{b}\equiv 1\pmod{2^{b}-1}$$

Now raising to the power $q$ and then multiplying by $2^r$ we have,
$$2^{bq+r}\equiv 2^{r}\pmod{ 2^{b}-1}$$
But $$bq+r=a$$
Therefore,
 $$2^{a}\equiv 2^{r}\pmod{ 2^{b}-1}$$
Adding one on both the sides
 $$2^{a}+1\equiv 2^{r}+1\pmod{ 2^{b}-1}$$

As $r<b$,
$$2^{r}+1<2^{b}-1$$

Therefore, $$2^{r}+1\not\equiv 0 \pmod{ 2^{b}-1}$$
Therefore, $2^{a}+1$ is not divisible by $2^{b}-1$ .

Can you show me where I went wrong?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495578/prove-2b-1-does-not-divide-2a-1-for-a-b2

Comment: Is my proof correct?