i am having trouble with understanding a number theory question's answer
I am new to number theory and I am having trouble understanding this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/456130/1311304 solution. I don't understand how $2^{a-b}+1$ is divisible by $2^b-1$ proves that $a<b$ and where the inequality $2^b-1\le2^a+1\le2^{b-1}+1$ came from.
I know this is basic number theory, probably some theorem but I basically started number theory one week ago so I don't know that many theorems.

First, there is no $2^a-b+1$ in the original post, there is $2^{a-b}+1$. Second, there is no $2^b-1\le 2^a+1\le 2^b+1$. There is $2^b-1\le 2^a+1\le 2^{b-1}+1$.
$2^b-1$ divides $2^a+1$ by the choice of $a$ and $b$. We have $$2^a+1=\color{red}{2^{a-b}(2^b-1)} +\color{blue}{2^{a-b}+1}.$$
Since the sum is divisible by $2^b-1$ and the red summand is too, then the blue summand must be divisible by $2^b-1$.
About $2^b-1\le 2^a+1\le 2^{b-1}+1$. First inequality follows from the fact that if $x\mid y$ for positive integers then $x\le y$.
The second inequality follows just from that $a\lt b$.

I understand the inequality now , I am confused about why 2^b-1 dividing 2^(a-b)+1 proves a can not be >=b

Ig my wording was bad I understand 2^b-1 had to divide 2^(a-b)+1 but I did not understand how this proves a<b

@Toshiv Because of choice of $a$. We got that $2^{a-b}+1$ is divisible by $2^b-1$. But $a$ was the minimal such number. Contradiction with fact that $a-b$ is even less than $a$.

Ok, thank you. I will go learn properties of minimal numbers then.

Assuming all are  positive integers  and  distinct. .
So if $m$ divides $n$, then $m< n$.
From given hypothesis
it follows that $2^b-1 < 2^a-b+1$ -----(1).
As subtracting  positive  $b$ from any number yields a smaller number,  we also get
$2^a-b+1< 2^a+1$ -----(2)
Combining the inequalities (1) and (2) we get $2^a-1 < 2^b-1$. This in turn shows $a<b$.

Sorry, did you follow the link provided by OP? They in fact are not interested in this inequality. They happened to have mistyped both their questions.

@Aig I don't know how to use mathjax and the person who edited my ques mistyped it

@Toshiv I corrected inequalities in your question. You should learn the basics of MathJax. It’s pretty easy. Just put $ around your formulae, that’s it, for the most part.

@Aig yup I will learn it, it's just all these EC's for college and then school work, Olympiad prep. I basically don't get any free time nowadays
